# How do you select only the first two div elements after it's sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using the slick.js plugin for a carousel. I would like to select only the first two elements after the `.slick0-current` class.

Hy HTML code is:

```
<div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide03" style="width: 150px;"></div>

<div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="4" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide04" style="width: 150px;"></div>

<div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="5" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide05" style="width: 150px;">next</div>
```

I'm able to select the `.slick0-current` class but I'm having problems selecting the two elements right after it. I've tried using something similar to `.slick-active:nth-child(2)` but this did not work for me.

My jQuery code is:

```
jQuery( ".slick-next").click(function() {
  jQuery(".slick-current").text("Im Previous");
  jQuery(".slick-active").siblings(".slick-slide.slick-active").eq(0).html("Im Current");
  jQuery(".slick-active").siblings(".slick-slide.slick-active").eq(2).html("Im After");

});
```

Comment: `.slick0-current + *` and `.slick0-current + * + *`

Comment: So when you click next, and slick fires to the next slide (3), and adds `slick-current` to slide (3), you want to select slide 4 and 5? Can you post your slick function as well please.

Comment: if it's the next and prev wrappers you want, why dont you use the settings `.slick({ nextArrow: '<div class="next">NEXT</div>', prevArrow: '<div class="next">PREV</div>' })`  ? then just `.find('.next')`

Comment: I've updated the code i'm not sure if that is what you're after, check the fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Every time you use ".slick-next" click function, isn't that going to confuse the slider towards the end of the carousel. Would it not be better to use slick events?

Updated demo.. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/6u314kwg/4/

```
$('.carousel').slick({

  // slick stuff

}).on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  $('.slick-current',this).prev().text("Im Previous");
  $('.slick-current',this).text("Im Current");
  $('.slick-current',this).next().text("Im After");

});
```

You can edit `afterChange` to `beforeChange` if you want the changes to happen before the animation.

This might be a little buggy but its a start. It should work if the carousel is infinite mode as it will just change the cloned slides.

Comment: You're absolutely right about using the slick events! Now if you look at OP comment below my answer, he added a requirement. ;)

Comment: @joshmoto This is lovely. Definitely easier

Comment: @Mariton I suddenly have a doubt about the "relevancy" of adding classes to non-visible slides... It's unclear why to do it. But I give up on this one ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I don't want to add classes to non-visible slides. Just visible ones

Comment: who won question?

Answer (score 1):

I did not recreate the whole slick demo here...

What you need are the [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) methods.

In the below demo, the elements in the resulting collection of element turn red.

```js
$(".slick-current").nextAll().filter(function(index){
  if(index<2){
   return this;
  }
}).addClass("inCollection");
```

```css
.inCollection{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide03" style="width: 150px;">one (current)</div>

<div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="4" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide04" style="width: 150px;">two</div>

<div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="5" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide05" style="width: 150px;">three</div>

<div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="6" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide05" style="width: 150px;">Four</div>

<div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="7" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide05" style="width: 150px;">Five</div>
```

Comment: I used your code in my full slick demo and it works nice https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/8rb7Ltue/

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette This is helpful but how can you create a unique class for the second and third elements. Fors example <div class="slick-slide slick-active inCollection2"> for second div and <div class="slick-slide slick-active inCollection3"> for the third div?

Comment: Well... That is different. You will have to select them in two steps then, the second->add a class, then the third->add another class. I suggest you to look at @joshmoto answer where that will be **way easier** to achieve since it already gives you the next slide.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Patrice Bessette Ahhhh! Makes sense. Thanks for your solution as well!